# VNC server not showing icons in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu, vnc, remote-desktop

I have installed vnc4server on my Ubuntu 18.04 vps server. Used ssh tunnel to connect on and via VNCviewer connected to it. I can't see icons in the start menu or the icons of the folders. Please see the screenshot attached.

[image: vnc4server-ubuntu18.04]
This is my xstartup file

```
nset SESSION_MANAGER
exec /etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc

[ -x /etc/vnc/xstartup ] && exec /etc/vnc/xstartup
[ -r $HOME/.Xresources ] && xrdb $HOME/.Xresources
xsetroot -solid grey
vncconfig -iconic &
xterm -geometry 80x24+10+10 -ls -title "$VNCDESKTOP Desktop" &
twm &
```

Comment: It's somewhat out of date, but perhaps something here will be helpful: [Missing icons for headless Xfce session via VNC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339593/missing-icons-for-headless-xfce-session-via-vnc)

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Followed the article, but still have the issue.

Comment: I suspect the issue is somewhere else that the xstartup. I have tried several different settings there and outcome is always same.

Answer (score 1):

After trying all the various vnc servers and many settings I have found the solution right under the spotlight.

In the **Applications > Settings > Appearance** I have changed the icons to different from the default and suddenly all the icons are there and working.

Finally!